# Why my Scala imperative style map creation snippet is slower than Java one?

Tags: java, scala, collections

I'm new to Scala, I'm trying to create a big map from IndexedSeq, I found a mention on SO that functional style map creation is much slower than imperative style Java one, decided to test it my self. So far I found out that not only Scala functional style code is slower but imperative too. What am I doing wrong, why my Scala code is several times slower? On my home computer it runs in 220 ms.(Java) and 460 ms.(Scala)

Scala [version](http://ideone.com/vpQlRX)

```
  private val testSize: Int = 1000000

  val seq: IndexedSeq[Int] = for (i <- 0 until testSize) yield Random.nextInt()

  val warmupMapt0 = System.nanoTime()

  var warmupMap: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int] = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]
  warmupMap.sizeHint(testSize)
  for (i <- 0 until testSize) warmupMap.put(i, seq(i))

  val t0 = System.nanoTime()
  var map: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int] = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]
  map.sizeHint(testSize)
  for (i <- 0 until testSize) map.put(i, seq(i))
  println((System.nanoTime() - t0)/ 1000000 + " ms.")
```

Java [version](http://ideone.com/kQ7X35)

```
private static final int TEST_SIZE = 1_000_000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] ar = new int[TEST_SIZE];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        ar[i] = random.nextInt();
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> warmupMap = new HashMap<>(TEST_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        warmupMap.put(i, ar[i]);
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(TEST_SIZE);
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        map.put(i, ar[i]);
    }
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - t0) / 1_000_000 + " ms.");
}
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799085/scala-perf-why-is-this-scala-app-30x-slower-than-the-equivalent-java-app?rq=1

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yeah, I saw it, that is why I added val warmupMapt0 = System.nanoTime() before a warp up and also tried running it from the console, it didn't help though.

Comment: could you add your timing results?

Comment: One thing you might want to address is that in the Scala version you get the time before creating the map and giving the sizeHint, in the Java version you do it the other way around.

Comment: @pedrofurla Yeah, tried it, it didn't change anything, maybe resource allocation is cheap, maybe it's done lazily.

Answer (score 3):

I think that one source of the problem is usage of an IndexedSeq. It is by default implemented by Vector which is generally a smart collection, but in your case it adds quite a large constant factor to creation of "array" of numbers and than accessing them by index. If you would like your code to be more equivalent to the java counterpart the following code would be the answer:

```
val ar = new Array(TestSize)
for (i <- 0 until TestSize) ar(i) = Random.next()
```

I read somewhere about foreach loops optimisation, can't find where, basically given enough warmup runs foreach loop should have similar efficiency compared to while loop, given function passed to it can be inlined.

**Edit**

Code can be further simplified:

```
val ar = Array.fill(TestSize)(Random.next())
```

Proposed by Alexey Romanov in comment.

Comment: I will try it when I get home, my office laptop show even bigger difference ~100ms\1000ms, I guess I need to read something about benchmarking, I didn't expect such a variety in results on different hardware/environments.

Comment: For the last sentence: unfortunately, no (or not yet). See http://downloads.typesafe.com/website/presentations/ScalaDaysSF2015/T2_Rytz_Backend_Optimizer.pdf starting with slide 37. The new optimizer in 2.12 does allow inlining it but doesn't do by default (and warmup is irrelevant for it).

Comment: You can also simplify to `val ar = Array.fill(TestSize)(Random.next())`.

Comment: You are right about simplification and issues regarding optimisation. Still i am almost certain i have seen benchmark showing only small difference in performance between while and foreach loop, it may be due to the different test methodology (function with heavy computation which outweights its invocation overhead), or explicit usage of proper compiler flags

Comment: I tried using array at my home computer with no success still ~ 220/460 ms. I guess you need to read generated byte-code to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `for` comprehension. In Scala they work in a very different way than `for` loops in Java and produce code which JVM can't optimize well enough. See e.g. http://www.scalablescala.com/roller/scala/entry/why_is_using_for_foreach or http://downloads.typesafe.com/website/presentations/ScalaDaysSF2015/T2_Rytz_Backend_Optimizer.pdf (starting with slide 37). You can work around this by using a `while` loop or a macro library like http://scala-blitz.github.io/,  https://github.com/non/spire or https://github.com/nativelibs4java/scalaxy-streams.